# In IF / ELSE evaluation, which code runs faster: large block of code in IF, or large block in ELSE?

Tags: powershell, if-statement

In Powershell, I have a script that does something if a file exists, and shows a message if it doesn't. I can write it in two ways:

```
IF (Test-Path $path_to_file) {run some elaborate code}
ELSE {write-host "File doesn't exist"}
```

Or I can do:

```
IF ((Test-Path $path_to_file) -eq $FALSE) {write-host "File doesn't exist"}
ELSE {run elaborate code}
```

These two do exactly the same thing. Will there be any difference in processing speed (assuming the 'elaborate code' is a long piece of code that parses long text files)?

Comment: `{run elaborate code}` is a `ScriptBlock` (as it is defined between curly brackets) . A `ScriptBlock` is only interpreted when it is required. Meaning that it will not make any difference when the `"file doesn't exist"`, the `{run elaborate code}` is not evaluated. I guess that you will find more difference due to the difference between the conditions, for performance testing you should use the same condition format `IF ((Test-Path $path_to_file) -eq $True) {run some elaborate code}...` for the first way to get a good comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if/else` statement executes once regardless, and should not affect the runtime of any code afterwards.

```
if (x) { <#short#> } else {
    #Long
}
```

This is generally more readable if it's a single line, you don't end up looking for where the `else` connects at the end of a long block of code when trying to read it back.

if there is any performance change it will likely be so minor that the readability of the above statement is magnitudes more important.

over 10000 iterations of 'meaningful' code, vs printing a string, the difference between if the code was in the If or Else was negligible (avg `0.038s`) and not reliably skewed to one result, I'd say you're safe to not even think about performance when considering this issue.